# Cordova: CSP issue on Android when requesting data over HTTPS

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3, osrm

> **Cordova** Android is an Android application library that allows for
>   Cordova-based projects to be built for the Android Platform. Cordova
>   based applications are, at the core, applications written with web
>   technology: HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Apache Cordova is a project of
>   The Apache Software Foundation (ASF).

I have developed an app with Cordova which works as expected on iOS, and on Android when the signed app gets deployed from Android Studio direct to a Samsung S6.

However, when downloading the app from Google Play it does not get requested data from a HTTPS request.

Here are the whitelist settings in the config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

And the CSP settings in the index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src *; connect-src *">
```

This is the request that does not get the data (without any meaningful error message - e.type is just an empty string)

```
_routingControl = L.Routing.control({
                                        plan: L.Routing.plan([
                                            L.latLng(coords),
                                            L.latLng(_userMarker.getLatLng())
                                        ],{
                                            createMarker: function() {return false}
                                        }),
                                        fitSelectedRoutes: true,
                                        autoRoute: true,
                                        show: false,
                                        serviceUrl: 'https://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute'
                                     });
```

Since this works on iOS I suppose there is an issue with the Whitelist/CSP setting.

Can somebody explain why this is not working when app is downloaded from the app store?

Comment: You should be able to get a more detailed error message using the Chrome Remote debugger's JavaScript console, CSP errors tend to be quite detailed so I would suggest you run the app with the remote debugger on and see what happens in the JS console.  That might shed light on what the problem is so we can suggest a fix. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: @SimonPrickett I do use Chrome remote debugger. As I said the signed app works when deployed from Android Studio to the device over USB, but not when downloaded from the app store.

Comment: Do you want the fix or an explanation?

Comment: when an app works when deployed from Android Studio, but doesn't work when downloaded from the play store, it's usually a server certificate problem, when the app is on the play store it has the debugable flag set to false and doesn't allow some certificates that it consider not safe (the certificate itself or the root certificate you used to sign it)

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 If you have a fix then please let me know.

Comment: @jcesarmobile Just to clarify: the app works when downloaded from play store, only the request to https://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute doesn't response the route data. So I suppose something is wrong with my Android whitelist/CSP settings.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that, if it work when deployed from android studio the whitelist/CSP should be fine, but not the server certificate

Answer (score 0):

@barbu,
your fix in just a second.

One of the things that is baffling me is developers going from a "Development IDE" to *Google Play*. As someone who builds with *Phonegap Build*, my workflow does not include a cable and 'adb'. Perhaps you can explain the reasoning with this process.

On you issues, you will need to implement the *whitelist* system.
This worksheet should help.
[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

There is also document that is link from there to the [Whitelist CSP Examples](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-csp-examples.md). In short, the way it is usually applied is the CSP is expanded from a webbrowser, then that meta element is added to the App. However in your case, you will likely work backwards.

### The Fix

Typically, when I give the answer I give the *whitelist* and *CSP*. You may be able to start with just the *CSP*. Best of Luck.

Add this to your `config.xml`

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" /> <!-- Required for iOS9 -->
```

**NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**
Add the following to your `index.html`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
         content="default-src *; 
                  style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                  script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

**Sidenote:** `gap:` from what I have right now, is only required for Cordova iOS, SEE: [Simon Mac Donald Adds](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-whitelist-system.md)