# Creating an Android Application from web page

Tags: android, html, cordova, web, web-applications

I am trying to create an app (to be specific a catholic prayer) from old printed book(No copyrights violation involved ).

Since i am newbie to Android app development, i think the easiest way (for me ) to do this for me as follows 
01.  create web page with scan images  from that book, and use phone gap to generate android version of this webpage.

My problem is this: Once i generated the android version , i was not able to see the image files. instead of that i can see only ? mark.

I want images to store in locally(inside the phone)  with the app so once users download this will not required to have an active internet connection to display those images.

I have added the web page preview and  screen shot from my android phone 
[image].

[image]

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: read some about `webview` https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: Does your content contain Flash? If so, Android WebView is not able to show flash content.

Comment: Could you provide some Code? The images are inside the PhonegapApp, right? Have you had a look at the [Conten Security Policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144820/cordova-csp-issue-on-android-when-requesting-data-over-https)?

Answer (score 0):

First look at the debug.
Don't forget to add

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Add this to make a new Webview.

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
webview.loadUrl("Your URL");
```

Otherwise try this tutorial:
http://www.technotalkative.com/android-webviewclient-example/