# Whats the most restricted Content-Security-Policy to enable facebook connect

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, content-security-policy

I would like to use facebook connect with ionic / Cordova.
it requires Content-Security-Policy.

What are the most restricted values for the following parameters that will still enable to use the facebook connect.
style-src 
script-src 
connect-src

Comment: well, just add nothing except those things you explicitly need...i dont use coridova anymore (is it still a thing with stuff like react native?), but i know that you can debug apps with chrome dev tools when you connect your phone, and if something gets blocked by CSP, there will be an error in the console.

Comment: Cordova is being used as part of "Ionic", which is alternative to react native, with its own pros & cons.
obviously "add nothing except those things you explicitly need." :)
the critical part that my question asks is what should I "explicitly need" for it.

Comment: I know, Cordova uses a simple Web View, while React Native and other modern tools use real native components - which is much better for the performance and comes with other benefits. anyway, i have created an answer, i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the minimum requirements that worked for me, to use facebook connect from ionic / cordova.
Big thanks for @luschn for guidance and assistant to debug it properly.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
content="style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
         script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 
                     http://localhost https://connect.facebook.net;
         connect-src 'self'
                        https://*.mydomain.com <!-- Replace with your own 
                                                    domain-->
                        https://*.facebook.net ws: wss:;
">
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you understand all those values. `style-src` is needed when you load external styles. `script-src` when you load external scripts. `connect-src` when you - for example - use an AJAX call. `connect-src` would be needed for calls to the Graph API:: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src

So if you load some JS SDK (like the FB JS SDK), and use it to do API Calls, you would need something like this: `"script-src 'self' *.facebook.com; connect-src 'self' graph.facebook.com"`

Not tested though. But with Cordova, as far as i remember, you can easily debug your App with Chrome Dev Tools, if you connect your phone. The console errors should tell you exactly what CSP value is missing.

Another thread that may help you: [Cordova: CSP issue on Android when requesting data over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144820/cordova-csp-issue-on-android-when-requesting-data-over-https)

In the end, just restrict as much as possible at the beginning and allow things one by one. You can easily find out what you need that way, and browser consoles do tell you exactly what´s missing and why.

Comment: connect-src 'self' graph.facebook.com
Thats the problematic part, it isn't sufficient for facebook.

And i am looking for the sufficient yet minimum requirements - if you dont have "Actual" experience with Ionic + Facebook connect, i wouldn't suggest you to waste time on guessing, it doesn't help neither of us.

Comment: i do have experience, i have used ionic and cordova in the past, and i am using facebook connect since many years, no worries ;) - also, i am using nginx quite extensively. and since i have used cordova and ionic, i know for sure that you can connect your phone and use the chrome dev tools for debugging. did you check it out? there should be errors if the CSP does not work.

Comment: to be honest, this feels disappointing. i believe i have already added a lot of helpful information. in fact, i know for sure that it´s correct and you can easily use the information to find out what´s wrong. so i am not sure where your comment comes from. your question was way too broad for stackoverflow to begin with. it shows no research and no information about what you have tried so far. so if you don´t want my help, so be it. remember, other people are here to help you figure stuff out, not to give you a finished solution.

Comment: anyway, besides facebook connect, are you doing some other stuff? for example, are you using the avatar image (url) of the user? that would be a different domain for the img-src: `img-src 'self' data: *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.com *.fbsbx.com` - hard to say though, all we know is "it does not work". what makes you think that connect-src is the problematic part?

Comment: thanks for the will to help.

safari doesn't display errors regarding it, xcode have "error" without details

This line works for me:
connect-src 'self' * ws: wss:;

Your line, isn't:
connect-src 'self' graph.facebook.com"

While i already verified that i need to use the ws, wss - the problem left is what urls should I whitelist instead of the *.

My question got -2 from some reason, but i do see it as valid and important question, and all the references i have seen online, where just "use *" it isn't secure, but it works.

I am looking for the right answer, the secure answer.

Comment: instead of graph.facebook.com, did you try with *.facebook.com too? btw, you should really use chrome dev tools instead, safari is not good for debugging. you can also try using * and check out the network tab in the dev tools, to find out which domains/urls are being used. and you´re right, if it works with *, connect-src should definitely be the problem. it´s perfectly fine to allow *.facebook.com then.

Comment: Many thanks for the guidance, I have produced an answer bellow.